# mongodb findByIdAndUpdate query and got SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
db.getCollection('comments').findByIdAndUpdate({"taskId": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(5b7fb3fe79c0831ec027a5bd)},{ '$push': { "commentDetail": { comment: 'sfsf fsdf' } }})
```

Here is my query. got Unexpected token ILLEGAL. I just getting started learning Mongo and Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use findOneAndUpdate. like

```
db.getCollection('comments').findOneAndUpdate({"taskId": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(5b7fb3fe79c0831ec027a5bd)},{ '$push': { "commentDetail": { comment: 'sfsf fsdf' } }})
```

Comment: still got syntax error but it works by using findOneAndUpdate from node side.thank you